# From request object to the database

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have an app with an AngularJS front-end and a Spring MVC back-end. I'm having some trouble with converting/mapping request objects to domain/dto objects.

On one page you can add a new order to the system, the POST payload would look something like this:

```
{
    memo: "This is some extra info for order",
    orderLines: [{productId:3, quantity:4}, {productId:2, quantity:5}, {productId:1, quantity:4}],
    shippingDate: "2014-10-08T19:16:19.947Z",
    warehouseId: 2
}
```

The Spring MVC controller method looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/order", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Void> addOrder(@RequestBody @Valid OrderRequest orderRequest, UriComponentsBuilder b) throws Exception {
     // the magic
}
```

Where OrderRequest is filled with the values of the POST request, the OrderRequest and        OrderLineRequest look like this:

```
public class OrderRequest {
    private Long id;

    private Date shippingDate;
    private String memo;
    private List<OrderLineRequest> orderLines;
    private Long warehouseId;

    public OrderRequest() {
    }

    // getters and setters ommitted
}

public class OrderLineRequest {
    private Long id;
    private String productCode;
    private int quantity;

    public OrderLineRequest() {
    }
}
```

My question now is, in order to save an `Order` object with `orderService.add(order)` I need to construct the Order object based on the values that were sent in the request. Where/how do I do this?

**OPTION 1**

The `OrderRequest` class could have a `makeOrder()` method with just returns an `Order` object like so:

```
public Order makeOrder() {
    Order order = new Order();
    order.setMemo(this.memo);
    order.setShippingDate(this.shippingDate);
    ...
}
```

Then I'd have to map the `OrderLineRequest` which could have their own `makeOrderLine` method:

```
public OrderLine makeOrderLine() {
    OrderLine orderLine = new OrderLine();
    orderLine.setQuantity = this.quantity;
    ...what to do with only the productId?
}
```

As you can see I can set the quantity but in the request I only received the `productId`, but in the database I save the `productCode`, `productName` as well, so I need that info from the database, but I don't want to make a database call from the Request object...I also don't want to half of the mapping in the request object and the rest of the mapping in the controller where I do have access to the services.

**OPTION 2**

I can use Dozer to do the mapping for me, but that would mean injecting the services into the Dozer custom converters which seem equally unclean to me...

**OPTION 3**

I pass the OrderRequest object to the service layer and let the service layer handle it, but my question would remain, how exactly would the service layer convert it, say you have the method `addOrder` like this:

```
public void addOrder(OrderRequest orderRequest) {

}
```

Would you call another service to convert from one to the other as I don't really want this conversion in a business logic method?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

use the `@RequestBody` to map your jsonObject that is send with the request , to a DTO .

please refer to the following [tutorial](http://hmkcode.com/spring-mvc-json-json-to-java/) .

hope that helps .

and please ask if there is something not clear .